# Different values on same data in Excel and MySql

Tags: mysql, excel, time

I have big problem with time sum, my table is something like this

```
------------------------------------------
| User_ID |StartTime|EndTime  | TimeDiff |
------------------------------------------
|    1    |08:00:00 |09:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
------------------------------------------
|    1    |09:00:00 |10:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
------------------------------------------
|    2    |06:30:00 |07:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
------------------------------------------
|    2    |07:00:00 |09:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
------------------------------------------
|    2    |09:00:00 |10:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
```

with sql syntax:

```
SELECT user_ID, TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(EndTime,StartTime)))
from timeTable
WHERE timeTable.user_ID=3387
```

in excel for my real data as result of sum I get `169:24:00`, but in mysql I get `164:04:00`

Where are my 5 hours and 20 minutes?

p.s.

tried:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(TIME_TO_SEC(EndTime),TIME_TO_SEC(StartTime))))...
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure excel is accurate? 2. Are you sure you have the exact same data in excel and mysql? 3. If you use `TIME_TO_SEC`, then you probably don't need to use `TIMEDIFF` anymore...

Comment: Well, excel was accurate until now, I 've checked several times data in excel and data in mysql and it is same, tried with SELECT SUM(SUBTIME(Endtime,StartTime)) ... and I got same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having dealt with enough date and time calculations in Excel, I would trust the total from MySQL and not the one from Excel. The way Excel handles time calculations is very unreliable and is prone to lose a few hours in large sums as it uses fractions to represent hours and minutes instead of using a proper data structure. I have [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/times-past-24.htm) and its [parent post](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/date-time-calculations.htm) to show this.

To answer your question, the lost 5 hours and 20 minutes are in the rounding of the fractions in Excel.